# install openstack identity service found "cliff.app not found(HTTP 404)"

Tags: installation, identity, openstack

it's the first time for me to ask question in stackoverflow.

Recently, I try to install the OpenStack follow by:http://docs.openstack.org/liberty/install-guide-ubuntu/keystone-services.html
but when I follow step by step, I met the trouble:

When I run the code in my virtual machine (ubuntu 14.04):

```
$ openstack service create --name keystone --description "OpenStack Identity" identity
```

it shows

> usage: openstack service create [-h] [-f {shell,table}] [-c COLUMN] [--variable VARIABLE] [--prefix PREFIX] [--name ] [--enable | --disable]
>
> openstack service create: error: unrecognized arguments: --description identity"

it seems the arguments "--description" and "identity" cannot be recognized, so I run

```
$ openstack service create -- name keystone identity
```

this time it show me

> "WARNING: kestoneclient.utils create takes at most 1 positonal argument(4 given)
>
> INFO: urllib3.connectionpool Starting new HTTP connection (1): controller
>
> ERROR: cliff.app Not Found (HTTP 404)"

I googling but I cannot find my answer, is it something wrong with my file conf? hope someone help me, thanks a lot~

Comment: any updates on this? I've also encountered the same error

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. You are following the Liberty release guide but installing the wrong release packages (probably Icehouse, the default for Ubuntu 14.04).

Try following the steps defined [here](http://docs.openstack.org/liberty/install-guide-ubuntu/environment-packages.html) in the Liberty installation guide to set up the Liberty repositories. In summary:

```
# apt-get install software-properties-common
# add-apt-repository cloud-archive:liberty
# apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade
```

and then you can install the correct client version

```
# apt-get install python-openstackclient
```